# c # regular expressions unsigned short,int,long

Tags: c#, regex

i am having a problem with dealing with regular expressions.
What i need is to make a regular expression that checks a bunch of numbers written through the console separated with spaces and to check how many of them is:
1) unsigned short 
2) unsigned  int
3) unsigned  long 
for someone like me without any regular expression experience it is like impossible.

Comment: So what is the question? "Please do my homework"?

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.---Jamie Zawinski

Comment: Let's assume the question is: "is this possible or reasonable, and if not, why"? Good answers to that below.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem that someone else is thinking about solving using regular expressions, quote Jamie Zawinski. And by "some people", I mean "all SO users". :)

Comment: @djacobson: What you say is clearly true, but if there is ever a clear case of "zomg, have to parse, I know, I'll use regular expressions, zomg, what are these things? Head splode", this is one.

Comment: @Jason: That's a valid point, but you're not getting it across by parroting the "two problems" quote.  All that does is annoy people.

Comment: @Alan Moore: If it's a valid point, it's not parroting. However, I understand what you mean; you're basically trying to say that the comment is not helpful to the OP; that might be true. A more helpful comment would have been "If you don't understand regular expressions, you might want to find a different approach to your problem."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to use regex? You could instead use `String.Split()`, `UInt32.TryParse()`, `UInt64.TryParse()` (unsigned long), and `UInt16.TryParse()` (unsigned short).

Comment: You can just as well call the methods using `uint.TryParse()`, `ulong.TryParse()` and `ushort.TryParse()`.

Answer (score 8):

Michael is right; *technically* the problem you face is one solvable by regular expressions. (Obviously; the language "strings which are legal unsigned long literals" is a *finite language* and therefore trivially a *regular language*. But it's a finite language with 16 billion billion members, which is rather a lot.)

In practice, you should write a regular expression that splits up the input string into *tokens* where a token is either whitespace or a string of numbers, and then write a non-regular-expression-based analyzer that figures out whether the number is a legal long, short, and so on.

Perhaps you could show the work you've done so far on the problem and ask a more specific question about what is stumping you.

Answer (score 4):

You are asking too much from RegEx...   it can certainly handle splitting the numbers up, but you should implement the logic to check what kind of number they are by iterating over each one outside of the Regex.

See Jon Skeet's excellent blog about this: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2005/09/21/67247.aspx